# batch_dot with variable batch size in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to writting a layer to merge 2 tensors with such a [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I49aj.png)

The shapes of x[0] and x[1] are both (?, 1, 500).

M is a 500*500 Matrix.

I want the output to be (?, 500, 500) which is theoretically feasible in my opinion. The layer will output (1,500,500) for every pair of inputs, as (1, 1, 500) and (1, 1, 500). As the batch_size is variable, or dynamic, the output must be (?, 500, 500).

However, I know little about axes and I have tried all the combinations of axes but it doesn't make sense.

I try with numpy.tensordot and keras.backend.batch_dot(TensorFlow). If the batch_size is fixed, taking a =
 (100,1,500) for example, batch_dot(a,M,(2,0)), the output can be (100,1,500).

Newbie for Keras, sorry for such a stupid question but I have spent 2 days to figure out and it drove me crazy :(

```
    def call(self,x):
            input1 = x[0]
            input2 = x[1]
            #self.M is defined in build function
            output = K.batch_dot(...)
            return output
```

Update:

Sorry for being late. I try Daniel's answer with TensorFlow as Keras's backend and it still raises a ValueError for unequal dimensions.

I try the same code with Theano as backend and now it works.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import keras.backend as K
Using Theano backend.
>>> from keras.layers import Input
>>> x1 = Input(shape=[1,500,])
>>> M = K.variable(np.ones([1,500,500]))
>>> firstMul = K.batch_dot(x1, M, axes=[1,2])
```

I don't know how to print tensors' shape in theano. It's definitely harder than tensorflow for me... However it works.

For that I scan 2 versions of codes for Tensorflow and Theano. Following are differences.

In this case, x = (?, 1, 500), y = (1, 500, 500), axes = [1, 2]

In tensorflow_backend:

```
return tf.matmul(x, y, adjoint_a=True, adjoint_b=True)
```

In theano_backend:

```
return T.batched_tensordot(x, y, axes=axes)
```

(If following changes of out._keras_shape don't make influence on out's value.)

Comment: I also tried loop, but " for i in x[0]" didn't work because Tensor is not iterable,  using K.get_shape(x[0])[0] it will return None

Comment: You're using lists instead of tuples for shapes. Shapes should be tuples: `shape = (dim1, dim2, dim3.....)`. You only use a list in the batch_dot function, where `axes = [1,2]`. Tuples use parentheses, lists use square brackets.

Comment: Also, there is an unecessary comma in `Input`, it should be `Input((1,500))`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It works well now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your multiplications should select which axes it uses in the batch dot function.

- Axis 0 - the batch dimension, it's your `?`
- Axis 1 - the dimension you say has length `1`
- Axis 2 - the last dimension, of size `500`

You won't change the batch dimension, so you will use `batch_dot` always with axes=[1,2]

But for that to work, you must ajust M to be (?, 500, 500).
For that define M not as (500,500), but as (1,500,500) instead, and repeat it in the first axis for the batch size:

```
import keras.backend as K

#Being M with shape (1,500,500), we repeat it.   
BatchM = K.repeat_elements(x=M,rep=batch_size,axis=0)
#Not sure if repeating is really necessary, leaving M as (1,500,500) gives the same output shape at the end, but I haven't checked actual numbers for correctness, I believe it's totally ok. 

#Now we can use batch dot properly:
firstMul = K.batch_dot(x[0], BatchM, axes=[1,2]) #will result in (?,500,500)

#we also need to transpose x[1]:
x1T = K.permute_dimensions(x[1],(0,2,1))

#and the second multiplication:
result = K.batch_dot(firstMul, x1T, axes=[1,2])
```

Comment: In Keras 2 Doc, I see this: For simple, stateless custom operations, you are probably better off using layers.core.Lambda layers. But for any custom operation that has trainable weights, you should implement your own layer.  Does it work when the layer needs a weight vectors to be optimized during the training?

Comment: What you expect from your layer doesn't need any trainable weight. It's just multiplication. Now, using a lambda layer in your model doesn't affect the other layers. If the other layers are trainable, they will be trained.

Comment: In this case, M is a trainable d*d Matrix to compute the similarity of 2 tensors. I need to optimize M during the training.

Comment: Updated. You can try not to repeat M like I did, I think it will result in the same, but keep in mind that M must reserve the first dimension for the batch.

Comment: So sorry for being late, I have updated the question. It does work. However there are some difference between tensorflow_backend and theano_backend. I don't know too much about theano but I hope the same call with different backend shall return same results in Keras.

Comment: Would you consider this as a valid answer? Please click the "check" mark :)

Comment: Thank u so much~~

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using TensorFlow so I tried to figure it out with TensorFlow in past few days.

The first one is much similar to Daniel's solution.

```
x = tf.placeholder('float32',shape=(None,1,3))
M = tf.placeholder('float32',shape=(None,3,3))
tf.matmul(x, M)
# return: <tf.Tensor 'MatMul_22:0' shape=(?, 1, 3) dtype=float32>
```

It needs to feed values to M with fit shapes.

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.matmul(x,M), feed_dict = {x: [[[1,2,3]]], M: [[[1,2,3],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]]})
# return : array([[[ 1.,  4.,  6.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Another way is simple with `tf.einsum`.

```
x = tf.placeholder('float32',shape=(None,1,3))
M = tf.placeholder('float32',shape=(3,3))
tf.einsum('ijk,lm->ikl', x, M)
# return: <tf.Tensor 'MatMul_22:0' shape=(?, 1, 3) dtype=float32>
```

Let's feed some values.

```
sess.run(tf.einsum('ijk,kl->ijl', x, M), feed_dict = {x: [[[1,2,3]]], M: [[1,2,3],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]})
# return: array([[[ 1.,  4.,  6.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Now M is a 2D tensor and no need to feed batch_size to M.

What's more, now it seems such a question can be solved in TensorFlow with `tf.einsum`. Does it mean it's a duty for Keras to invoke `tf.einsum` in some situations? At least I find no where Keras calls `tf.einsum`. And in my opinion, when batch_dot 3D tensor and 2D tensor Keras behaves weirdly. In Daniel's answer, he pads M to (1,500,500) but in K.batch_dot() M will be adjusted to (500,500,1) automatically. I find tf will adjust it with [Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) rules and I'm not sure Keras does the same.