# Concatenate numpy array and keras layers

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I have a problem:

Im trying to make simple self-driving cars, that can drive smooth and control throttle and break.

And i got such problem:

I can't concatenate VGG_16 model from keras and current car speed.

Already tried:

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from Train import *
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers import concatenate
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K


images, speed, labels = LoadGPS_SPEED() # load training data, image, car speed and label ([0, 1, 0], for example. Where [0 - left turn, 1 - throttle, 0 - right turn] 

speed = speed.reshape(speed.shape[0], 1) # reshape to shape[0], 1, because speed is just a number (20, for example)

speed = K.variable(speed) # here is some magic, which i tired, because without that i got other error, lol. P.S Right after loading, images, speed and labels - are just numpy arrays

vgg_conv = VGG16(weights='imagenet', # VGG from default keras application
             include_top=False)

for layer in vgg_conv.layers[0:-4]:
    layer.trainable = False

input = Input(shape=(60,60,3),name = 'image_input')

output_vgg16_conv = vgg_conv(input)

conv_flat = layers.Flatten()(output_vgg16_conv)
conv_flat = concatenate([speed, conv_flat]) # trying to concatenate speed and flatten layer
conv_flat = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(conv_flat)
conv_flat = layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv_flat)
conv_flat = layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(conv_flat) # 3 possible actions
```

and just got such error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/Python_Projects/ProjectCars/ModelGenerate.py", line 34, in
>   
>       conv_flat = concatenate([speed, conv_flat])
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\merge.py", line 649, in
>   concatenate
>       return Concatenate(axis=axis, **kwargs)(inputs)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line
>   431, in **call**
>       self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\merge.py", line 362, in
>   build
>       'Got inputs shapes: %s' % (input_shape))
>
> ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes
>   except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(10, 1), (None, 512)]

Please, help me. Im just a beginner and don't know, how to fix that :c

Comment: speed dim is (10,1) so it doesn't have dim for batch size, or you are using 1 as batch size?

Comment: @Zaher88abd, hmm, im using 10 "speed data" with 1 dim. (10 arrays with 1 value). P.S It was just test. P.S.S Images, labels also have 10 arrays

Comment: So, what I understand from you speed is 2 dim array and conv_flat is 1 dim array (if we take out the batch dim). that is not right, as I know there is no way to concatenate different shape array together.

Comment: Also, I recommend reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44087528/3241790)